# Cannot inherit from final

Tags: java, android

I have a java image analysis program and am trying to get it to run on android. It starts like this (working on standard java):

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
public MaskImage(BufferedImage srcImage) {
    super(srcImage.getWidth(), srcImage.getHeight(), srcImage.getType());
    this.srcImage = srcImage;
    this.height = srcImage.getHeight();
    this.width = srcImage.getWidth();
}
```

When I try to get it working on android studio however I change `bufferedimage` to Bitmap, but still run into a couple of problems:

1. I cannot extend Bitmap in the same way I could `BufferedImage`
2. `super(srcImage.getWidth(), srcImage.getHeight(), srcImage.getType());`

this line runs into multiple issues, Says:

> expected Parameters; actual: Arguments;

Thanks For any Help!

Comment: Well, it's final isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know, Bitmap is `final`. By the very definition of final classes in Java, this means you cannot subclass it.

You will need to find an alternate strategy for accomplishing whatever you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps creating a class that wraps a Bitmap is one solution.

Comment: Thank you. where should I look to for creating a class that wraps a Bitmap and what would it accomplish?

Comment: That is completely dependent on what you are trying to do. If you are trying to transform a Bitmap to display in an ImageView, you will likely be better off manipulating the Bitmap itself.